# Is it posible to list all file names on my website on webserver from an specific directory with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, apache, webserver

I am trying to get a list of files(pdf) or at least their names from an directory. With pure js it seams simple with require('fs') and that stuff. But on my Webserver its not that simple.

I hope sofern can help me

Comment: "fs" library is specific to nodejs and not in the "browser js"
what you want to do can be achieved with a server application

Answer (score 0):

Due to security reasons, it‘s not directly possible to read the folder structure of servers. You could create a JSON file where a list of all PDF files lays and then `fetch()` this file from the website and display a list. You can assemble links from these names by adding something like

```
https://server.example/files/
```

to the beginning of the filenames.

How to use `fetch()`:

```
fetch('your url')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

I wish you much luck

Comment: What should i do when i upload a pdf file. How could i add the uploaded file to this list of files?

Comment: Well, your server could then edit the file and simply append the file to the list. If that‘s not possible, the only real possibilities is to edit the file manually